# Pass a parameter to a template?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template login called in different pages with:

```
{{>login}}
```

This template is a form with a button submit. When a user clicks on submit, I route to an other page like this:

```
Template.login.events({

  'click #submit' : function() {

  Router.go('player', {_id: username});
 }
});
```

What I want to do is to be able to route to different pages according the pages where the template {{>login}} is. Is it possible without duplicating the template? Like having a parameter passed to the template and switching in the event function according this parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to pass a parameter to a template :

```
{{> login parameter="value"}}
```

And this is how you can access it in the event handler :

```
Template.login.events({
  "click #submit":function(event,template){
    // this is important if you want to avoid page reload
    event.preventDefault();
    switch(this.parameter){
      // ...
    }
  }
});
```

The parameter could also be a helper :

```
{{> login helper}}

Template.login.helpers({
  helper:function(){
    return ...;
  }
});
```

I can't find something about it in the docs though, but it's standard handlebars stuff.

Comment: For your information: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#inclusion-and-block-arguments

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

```
{{> login route='player'}}
```

Then update your javascript to:

```
Router.go(this.route, /* ... */);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass a parameter, or several, to the template which can set the data context the template uses.

```
{{> login route="someRouteName" routeParams=getRouteParameters}}
```

This will set the data context of the template to an object containing two properties: `route` and `routeParams` (assuming there's a helper named `getRouteParameters` that will return a parameter object).

You can then use these from template helpers or, in your case, from within your event handler.

```
Template.login.events({
  'click #submit' : function(event, template) {
    var routeName = template.data.routeName;
    var routeParams = template.data.routeParams;

    Router.go(routeName, routeParams);
  }
});
```